# slsart deploy throwing error, how do I troubleshoot?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, load-testing, serverless, artillery

I am trying to use the command "slsart deploy" but it's not working for me. How do I troubleshoot the error below?

```
slsart deploy           
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/type/lib/resolve-exception.js:14
        throw error;
        ^

TypeError: undefined is not an array
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/type/lib/resolve-exception.js:12:14)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/type/array/ensure.js:15:25)
    at new Serverless (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/serverless.js:86:22)
    at Object.serverlessLoader (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless-artillery/lib/index.js:542:24)
    at Object.deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless-artillery/lib/index.js:563:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless-artillery/bin/serverless-artillery:205:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```